How do I repair a problem with Launchpad?
I keep getting an error message from Launchpad about E conflicting values for option Signed-By regarding https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yannubuntu/ubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/ and so forth whenever I try to repair the boot. I am running ubuntu 24.04. All the previous questions are for early Ubuntus like 12 or 14. Please help.

Your URL is wrong - the correct URL is:
http://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/

Which is evident from the Launchpad site.
